# Project Creation While via VS code in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to create the Project from my terminal windows in VS code from running the command as below:

```
sfdx force:project:create -n "LWC Session"
```

Getting error as below :

{WARNING: apiVersion configuration overridden at "45.0"
ERROR running force:project:create:  Name must contain only alphanumeric characters.}

Please help me out for this.

Comment: Space (" ") character is not alphanumeric character

Comment: that's not the issue here I can create a project with that name, seems like a config error for the cli.

Comment: @AtlasCan indeed correct, I can create such a project

Comment: Should i Uninstall the CLI and install again??

Comment: @AtlasCan actually after updating sfdx into 7.30, I can not anymore, so seems to be recent change

Comment: @AbhijeetKumar please try to create project without space in name

Answer (score 1):

`sfdx force:config:set apiVersion=46.0` can you run this and try again?

Comment: C:\Users\ABHIJEET KUMAR>sfdx force:config:set apiVersion=46.0
WARNING: apiVersion configuration overridden at "45.0"
=== Failures
NAME        MESSAGE
──────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
apiVersion  This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project. Add the --global flag to set config outside of a project. Getting this error

Comment: Yes it got created Without the Space Between "LWCSession"